# Do we really need "meaning-in-context" as tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know other sites use [meaning-in-context](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), but do we really need it?

Since I cannot generically ask the meaning of a word without describing exactly what I find confusing, or giving an example of sentence that confuses me about the meaning of a word or how to use it, I am already giving a context for the meaning.
I cannot ask a generic question like *What does "gambo" mean?* or it would be probably closed as too broad.

Also, it is not that if a question is not using [meaning-in-context](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), then I can assume the meaning reported in the answers is the generic meaning the word has.

Comment: Compared to English, individual Esperanto words have less possible meanings and they depend less on context (textual and social). So the usefulness of this tag is much lower in Esperanto, making it very very similar to "word-meaning".

Comment: Words never have meaning outside of context in any natural languages. Context is essential. I'd recommend you turn word-meaning into a synonym of meaning-in-context just to remind everyone to explain the context they saw/heard the words they asked about being used in.

Comment: @curiousdannii The context is always given from the question, as it is with every question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest merging this with the [word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) tag.

When someone asks what a word means, there's an implied requirement that they're *not* simply asking someone to look something up in a dictionary to recite the definition. Questions are usually asking about an idiomatic expression or a difficult-to-translate concept that *warrants* asking on a site like this. But that's an issue of relative *quality…* and ***not*** a different use case, as suggested by having *two* different tags.

[word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) and [meaning-in-context](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) are essentially the same thing.